# CLBeacon does not get detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am trying to understand the working of CLBeacons. I have previously worked with CBPeripherals which is actually the corebluetooth framework implemnetation for BLE devices.

What I did was the following steps:

1. Used a CBPeripheralManager to detect the beacons around me, (to get each beacon's individual identifier).
2. Used the data to be displayed on UITableView
3. On Selecting a Tableview, I am passing the CBPeripheral object itself, to another class where I have a CLLocationManager. Here I define the CLBeaconRegion with the proximity UUID of the CBPeripheral object and startToRangeBeacons in that region.

No beacons appear.

Surprisingly, when I use [NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"] as the uuid (which I gathered from the AirLocate project), multiple beacons appear.

As per the docs I've read, the proximity UUID is the beacon's identifier. So why is it not working when I use the passed identifier, and why is it working when I am using a defined identifier?

Code ----
1. The First Screen

```
#import "TiBViewController.h"
#import "DEASensorTag.h"
#import "TiBScanTableViewCell.h"
#import "TiBLocateViewController.h"

@interface TiBViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *timer_check;
@end

@implementation TiBViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    [self performSelector:@selector(initialise) withObject:self afterDelay:2.0];
}
-(void)initialise
{
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager initSharedServiceWithDelegate:self];
    if (centralManager.isScanning == NO)
    {
        [centralManager startScan];
        centralManager.isScanning=YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    }

    if(self.timer_check==nil)
    {
        self.timer_check = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:20
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(timer_function)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];

        NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runner addTimer:self.timer_check forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
    [self.timer_check fire];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    switch (central.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Device is Supported"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
        {

            break;
        }
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            break;

        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager findPeripheral:peripheral];
    yp.delegate = self;

    [yp readRSSI];

    for (TiBScanTableViewCell *cell in [self.peripheralsTableView visibleCells])
    {
        if (cell.yperipheral == yp)
        {
           [cell updateDisplay];
            break;
        }
    }
}



- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    for (TiBScanTableViewCell *cell in [self.peripheralsTableView visibleCells])
    {
        [cell updateDisplay];
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];

    YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager findPeripheral:peripheral];
    if (yp.isRenderedInViewCell == NO)
    {
        yp.isRenderedInViewCell = YES;

        [self.peripheralsTableView reloadData];
    }

    if (centralManager.isScanning)
    {
//        if(advertisementData!=nil)
//        {
//            NSLog(@" ad is %@",advertisementData);
//        }

       for (TiBScanTableViewCell *cell in [self.peripheralsTableView visibleCells])
        {
          if (cell.yperipheral.cbPeripheral == peripheral)
            {
              if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateDisconnected)
                {
                    cell.rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld dB", (long)[RSSI integerValue]];

                    cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" distance : %0.3fm",[self calculateAccuracyWithRSSI:[RSSI doubleValue]]];
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals {
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];

    for (CBPeripheral *peripheral in peripherals)
    {
        YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager findPeripheral:peripheral];
        if (yp)
        {
            yp.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    [self.peripheralsTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
{
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];

    for (CBPeripheral *peripheral in peripherals)
    {
        YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager findPeripheral:peripheral];
        if (yp)
        {
            yp.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    [self.peripheralsTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - CBPeripheralDelegate Methods

- (void)performUpdateRSSI:(NSArray *)args
{
    CBPeripheral *peripheral = args[0];

    [peripheral readRSSI];
}

- (void)peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: readRSSI failed, retrying. %@", error.description);

        if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected)
        {
            NSArray *args = @[peripheral];
            [self performSelector:@selector(performUpdateRSSI:) withObject:args afterDelay:2.0];
        }

        return;
    }

    [self placeRSSI:peripheral];

    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager findPeripheral:peripheral];

    NSArray *args = @[peripheral];
    [self performSelector:@selector(performUpdateRSSI:) withObject:args afterDelay:yp.rssiPingPeriod];
}

-(void)placeRSSI:(CBPeripheral *)per
{
    for (TiBScanTableViewCell *cell in [self.peripheralsTableView visibleCells])
    {
        if (cell.yperipheral)
        {
            if (cell.yperipheral.isConnected)
            {
                if (cell.yperipheral.cbPeripheral == per)
                {
                    cell.rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", per.RSSI];
                    cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" distance : %0.3fm",[self calculateAccuracyWithRSSI:[per.RSSI doubleValue]]];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark UITableView
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    return centralManager.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";

    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager peripheralAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    TiBScanTableViewCell *pcell = (TiBScanTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [pcell configureWithPeripheral:yp];

    yp.isRenderedInViewCell = YES;
    cell = pcell;

    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager peripheralAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    TiBLocateViewController *locate = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Locate"];
    locate.cbPeripheral=yp.cbPeripheral;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locate animated:YES];
}
-(void)timer_function
{
    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    for (TiBScanTableViewCell *cell in [self.peripheralsTableView visibleCells])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.peripheralsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        YMSCBPeripheral *yp = [centralManager peripheralAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [centralManager removePeripheral:yp];
        [self.peripheralsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.timer_check invalidate];
    self.timer_check = nil;
    [self timer_function];

    DEACentralManager *centralManager = [DEACentralManager sharedService];
    [centralManager stopScan];

    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (double)calculateAccuracyWithRSSI:(double)rssi
{
    if (rssi == 0) {
        return -1.0;
    }

    double txPower = -70;
    double ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
    if (ratio < 1.0) {
        return pow(ratio,10);
    }
    else {
        double accuracy =  (0.89976) * pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;
        return accuracy;
    }
}
@end
```

1. The Second Screen

   #import "TiBLocateViewController.h"
       @import CoreLocation;

   ```
   @interface TiBLocateViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
   @property (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locateManager;
   @end

   @implementation TiBLocateViewController

   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
   {
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
       if (self) {
           // Custom initialization
       }
       return self;
   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       self.locateManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
       self.locateManager.delegate=self;
       self.locateManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

   }

   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewDidAppear:YES];

   }
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
   {
       if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
       {

           NSUUID *per_uuid = self.cbPeripheral.identifier;
           CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]
                                           initWithProximityUUID:per_uuid
                                           identifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

           beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
           beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
           beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;

           [manager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
           [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];

       }
   }
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {
       if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
       {
           [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
       }
   }
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {
       if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
       {
           [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
       }
   }
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
   {
      for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons)
      {
          NSLog(@" beacon %@",beacon);
      }
   }
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
       NSLog(@" error is %@",error.localizedDescription);
   }
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {
       if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
       {
           [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
       }
   }
   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   }
   -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
       [self.locateManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
   }
   /*
   #pragma mark - Navigation

   // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
   }
   */

   @end
   ```

Comment: The basic issue that I was trying to achieve was to locate CBperipheral. Since CB ends with peripheral, I thought to try in CLBeacons

Comment: you take the uuid from CB and start ranging with CL .. sounds good

Comment: edited post with code

Comment: didChangeAuthorizationStatus isn't called when the status doesn't change... if it is ... it shouldn't be :D don't rely on it

Comment: I had it at first on the ViewDidAppear block, the same problem was there, so I thought to move it to some place else; Nothing happened either.....:(

Comment: Yep. It's the same since the per_uuid is displayed in the TableViewCell

Comment: mhm make zip of the project and ill look at it here right now.

Comment: How do I send you the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although iBeacons use Bluetooth Low Energy, they are not used with the Core-Bluetooth library in iOS.  They are handled through Core Location.

A beacon region is defined in terms of three parameters - the UUID, the major and the minor.

An iBeacon UUID is different to a Bluetooth MAC address - it is more like a "vendor id".  All beacons for a given vendor or owner will have the same UUID - e.g. Acme Dept store will allocate themselves a UUID and assign it to all of their beacons, while Big Bank Corp will allocate a different one and assign it to theirs.  They can then use the major and minor to indicate different locations.  For example the department store might have major=store number and minor=department number (shoes=1, food=2 and so on).  For the bank major might be branch location and minor could be location in a branch (1=teller, 2=ATM, 3=back office).

There are also some "well known" UUIDs in use - You found the AirLocate one for example.  Estimote also have one that their beacons ship with by default.

When you want to scan for beacon regions you must specify the UUID as a minimum.  You can also optionally specify the major and minor.  When a beacon is detected that matches the beacon region for which you are scanning you will receive the notification (either didEnter/ExitRegion or didRangeBeacon depending on what modes you have activated).

Some beacons may additionally implement BLE peripheral services and characteristics for setting their parameters (UUID, major, minor, transmit level) but this is not part of the iBeacon spec so different vendors will have different methods for doing this.  To work with these settings you would use Core-Bluetooth.

So, in summary, if you are just dealing with the iBeacon side of things then you don't need to do anything with Core-Bluetooth.  All you need is Core-Location.

Comment: A very clear explanation.But what does the UUID of the CBPeripheral indicate? Is it not the same as Proximity UUID of the CLBeaconRegion?

Comment: IBeacons use bluetooth low energy chipsets so they do have a bluetooth mac and as I said they may expose auxiliary ble services but you don't need to worry about it for iBeacon purposes

Comment: So, basically I need to know what company produced my iBeacons, then program it's proximity UUID for the CLBeaconRegion, right?

Comment: Yes, or there may be an app from the vendor that you can use to set your own UUID

Comment: Ok a new question. So, with this thing, should I have a webservice to identify the beacon and load some information on detection, or can the iBeacon itself carry the information?

Comment: The beacon can only carry the three bits of information. You need to use these to access some information, whether via web service or a database built in to your app

Comment: Ok. Can I detect iBeacons in background mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412517/how-to-detect-ibeacon-device-in-background

Comment: aeh... this is all true but how is this an answer? the op said the uuid he sees with CB equals the beacon UUID

Comment: a CB id is the same as the beacon uuid I'd think!?

Comment: iBeacon uses the BLE advertising protocols, so you can discover them through Core-Bluetooth, but to do anything useful with the you should use Core-Location, so I guess you summarise the answer as "you can discover iBeacons with Core Bluetooth, but don't"